# Validade de um QR Code

Tags: qrcode

Tenho um QR Code que leva à um link. Esse link, suponho, que ficará no ar até 2015.
Claro, quando o link não existir, esse QR Code não levará a lugar algum.

Minha dúvida é: Esse código tem validade? Ou, por exemplo, alguém lá na Transilvânia pode gerar um QR Code idêntico ao meu.

Pergunto isso, pois, pretendo armazená-los.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Tenho um QR Code que leva à um link. Esse link, suponho, que ficará no ar até 2015. Claro, quando o link não existir, esse QR Code não levará a lugar algum.**

- É basicamente isso. Provavelmente ele vai para um 404 ou para um servidor não encontrado.

**Minha dúvida é: Esse código tem validade?**

- O código será lido a qualquer momento, pois a informação nele contida não depende de nada externo.

**Alguém lá na Transilvânia pode gerar um QR Code idêntico ao meu?**

- Com certeza. O conteúdo do QR Code é apenas um stream de bytes, que tem como saída uma string. Basta alguém usar a mesma string, e eis o QR com valor idêntico. E o mais legal, nem precisa estar na Transilvânia pra isso.

  Inclusive, se a pessoa utilizar a mesma compressão e critério de encoding, a imagem será idêntica.

**Pergunto isso, pois, pretendo armazená-los.**

- Pretende armazenar a imagem ou o link? (lembrando que não são apenas links que podem ser armazenados,num QR Code. Qualquer string pode ser armazenada, com as mais diversas finalidades)

  As finalidades mais comuns são os links, dados de conexão wi-fi e cartões de visita eletrônicos. Mas ainda há os códigos de uso interno, como identificação de embalagens, ou qualquer outra coisa que você possa imaginar que substitua os códigos de barra convencionais.

  Se for armazenar as imagens, provavelmente estará armazenando mais informação que o necessário, a não ser que tivesse um uso muito especial para as características de encoding utilizadas (o que é improvável).

> **Sugestão para quem for criar os próprios códigos:**

Não utilize links curtos de terceiros. Crie o seu sistema de links curtos, e armazene no seu próprio DB os dados, de preferência sob um domínio de internet que você possa manter pelo tempo que desejar.

Veja os principais motivos:

- Você evita que o link "expire", ou deixe de existir caso o provedor do link curto tenha problemas ou prazo.
- Você pode corrigir um link errado. Já vi um caso em que uma revista de grande escala teve que entrar num acordo com um encurtador de links famosos, graças a um link que foi publicado errado na capa da revista. Se você gerencia seus próprios links, basta trocar o errado pelo correto no DB, e o problema está resolvido.
- Você pode apontar um QR de um link antigo para uma mensagem amistosa avisando que o link expirou, em vez de simplesmente quebrar o acesso, criando uma experiência melhor pro usuário, e quem sabe o direcionando para alguma outra coisa interessante, não perdendo a visita.

Obs: digo links curtos, pois quanto menos informação, melhor a legibilidade de um QR Code. Lembre-se que quando for o caso, dá pra usar praticamente 7KB em um único código, mas na prática, só com um scanner profissional você terá certeza de ler um QR com tanta informação.

Aliás, eu humildemente ouso dizer que o pessoal que normatizou o recibo da **[NFC-e](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nfc-e)** - que começou a ser usada em alguns estados no lugar do cupom fiscal - fez uma grande besteira pondo muita informação desnecessária no QR Code, tornando o mesmo "inescaneável" por muitos dispositivos. E olhe que uma das premissas era a do comerciante economizar na impressora utilizada. Na prática, a impressora tem que ser boa, e o leitor também. Se tivessem feito de maneira mais sensata, até uma impressora matricial resolveria.

Comment: Muito bem explicado, valeu!

Answer (score 6):

A maior parte das soluções deste tipo<sup>[Citation needed]</sup> envolvem a definição de expiração no banco de dados, sendo o código presente no QR Code apenas um `ID` apontando para o registro.

A codificação de expiração diretamente no código pode utilizar um um valor que expressa um *TimeStamp* definindo o prazo ou data de validade.

Você precisará de, no máximo, 8 bytes para armazenar um *TimeStamp* definido [de acordo com ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601).

[De acordo com a entrada na Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_code#Storage), um QR Code pode conter até 7089 bytes (ou aprox. 6.9 kb).

Answer (score 3):

Acredito que não tenha validade, pois o QR Code é um padrão, como é o código de barras. Quando um leitor de QR Code é usado para ler seu código, irá simplesmente traduzir o código no link que você usou para cria-lo.

Eu mesmo fiz o teste, achei uma revista de uns 2 anos atrás com um código e ele leu normalmente, apenas o link que havia nele não existia mais.